# Finding linear regression equation with unequal sample sizes

Tags: linear-regression

The data samples $x$ and $y$ for question $2$ are unequal. Here, we have more $y$ points than $x$ points. How do I go about solving that?

I just need help with the calculations. Once I know how to do the calculations I can just translate that into Java code.

Also, is it necessary to figure out the standard error or could I leave that out?

[image]

**EDIT: Sorry, I though that question 2 was different. For some reason the physical length of the sample data for x and y made it seem like y had more sample data.**

Comment: They're equal..

Comment: Sorry, I though that part 2 was different. For some reason the physical length of the sample data for x and y made it seem like y had more sample data.

Comment: @RabMakh Thanks for pointing it out. Is it necessary to figure out the standard error or could I leave that out?